# Recoll: Removing directories from Xapian db after indexing

Tags: directory, delete, recoll

Directories can be excluded from Recoll indexing with the parameter `skippedPaths` in `recoll.conf`.

1. Does this remove the skipped directory data from Xapian db if the directory was indexed earlier?
2. If it doesn't, how can I remove the directory data from the Xapian db?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the configuration file should cause the monitoring process to run an incremental indexing pass (as a new process actually), and this should cause the deletion from the index of the data for the new skippedPaths entry.

If you have a test case where this does not work, please detail it on the recoll issue tracker: https://framagit.org/medoc92/recoll/-/issues